# TDengine renaming the result in query

Tags: tdengine

In MySQL, the renamming the the fetched result can be renamed through 'c1 and c2', or 'c1 c2'. In the Documentation, it says 'c1 and c2' is supported , but nothing can be found about 'c1 c2'.
Is 'select c1 c2 from table' supported by TDengine?

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1,c2 from table
```

or if you want to use alias

```
select c1 as xxx, c2 as xxx from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use select c1 xxx, c2 xxx from table, which ignores the as keywords.